# Reclaim master after unwanted merges (git)

Tags: git, merge

I am wondering what the best approach is to cleaning up after a merge that it turns out I didn't want.

My tree looked like this:

```
     F---G topic1,v1
    /     \
A---B---C---D---E master
```

After merging `topic1,v1` into `master`, I realized that v1 was not the correct approach. So I created a new branch from B, and implemented v2.

At this point, there were only a few commits on `master` that I needed, so I cherry picked them onto the v2 branch and used `update-ref` to point `master` to this new branch.

```
     F---G topic1,v1
    /     \
A---B---C---D---E master
    \      
     H---I topic1,v2
         \
          C---E master'
```

The only remaining issue was that I had already pushed `master` to origin. Fortunately, I'm the only dev. Since I really do want to abandon the old `master`, I reasoned it was okay to `push --force`. But I never like that, so I was wondering if there's a better way to approach this whole situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a perfectly reasonable situation for a forced push. You are the only dev on the repo you say, so you won't need to worry about stomping out someone's work. Presumably you also understand that any feature branches that were forked off of the old, abandoned master branch's commits will be difficult to merge into the new master branch, and you've weighed it in your mind that you really do want to discard those change sets.

And in git, nothing is ever really lost, if you're worried about wanting the old commits for historical purposes. Branches are cheap; create a copy of your master branch (`git checkout -B master_abandoned` from the head of your original master branch) before you reset and force-push, and you'll be able to easily reference it in the future for as long as you decide to keep the branch around.